# Zero Footprint Python-Social-Auth authentication

Tags: python, django, oauth, oauth-2.0, python-social-auth

My site has regular users that use the django default User model, but for one particular functionality, I want people to be able to login using their social accounts (twitter, fb..etc) using python-social-auth without having these logins saved in the database with the user model (no accounts created, no ability to do certain normal user tasks) and with a session timeout.

I looked around for ways to do that but my little research bore no fruit. Any ideas?

Summary:

1. Separation between normal users and social (so I can limit what social auth'd users can do)
2. Session timeout for social auth'd users
3. No addition in the User table for social auth'd users (no footprint).
4. Optional: Obtain their social username and id for logging purposes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to approach this problem by using `django.contrib.auth.models.Group` and `django.contrib.auth.models.Permission`. Create one general group with custom permissions to your apps' functionality and add all your normal users to that.

Save accounts created by `python-social-auth` in default `django.contrib.auth.models.User` but create seperate Group without any permissions for them.

If necessary create some scheduled task ( either with cronjob or Celery ) which will go through users and deactivate/delete those who expired.

Answer (score 1):

You can differentiate the social user by adding a custom user model for `python-social-auth` by adding the setting `SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL`. Check the setting docs at http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/configuration/settings.html#user-model

Comment: I tried that but upon running syncdb it threw the error:

CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
auth.user: Accessor for m2m field 'groups' clashes with related m2m field 'Group.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'groups'.
auth.user: Accessor for m2m field 'user_permissions' clashes with related m2m field 'Permission.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_permissions'.
main.voter: Accessor for m2m field 'groups' clashes with related m2m field 'Group.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'groups'.

Comment: That looks like an issue in your custom model definition, a few fields in your models class with the related names in the django built-in user model, how's your model defined?

Comment: I tried :

class Voter(User):
    pass

and 
class Voter(AbstractUser):
    pass

Comment: Then you are inheriting fields that clash with the django built-in user model, the django user system is not thought to have multiple user models at the same time in an application. You need a completely unrelated user model.